# Find difference in array only using key using lodash

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I find all values in an array A - where the key is not in array B ( a bit like a SQL Not In ) .  I don't want to compare the whole array , just one property - but I do want to return all fields for the differences using lodash ( or simpler )

```
const arrayA = [
  { sku:"1", name:"one"},
  { sku:"2", name:"two"}
]
const arrayB = [
  { sku:"1", name:"One Product"},
  { sku:"2", name:"Two Product"},
  { sku:"3", name:"Three Product"}
]
```

The results should be :

```
{ sku:"3", name:"Three Product"}
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need lodash for this.
What you need is to filter the second array and eliminate all elements existing in the first array.

```js
const arrayA = [
  { sku:"1", name:"one"},
  { sku:"2", name:"two"}
]
const arrayB = [
  { sku:"1", name:"One Product"},
  { sku:"2", name:"Two Product"},
  { sku:"3", name:"Three Product"}
]

console.log(
  // filter B such that we only leave items from B that are not in A
  arrayB.filter(b => 
    !arrayA.some(a => a.sku === b.sku)
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use:

```
const arrayA = [
  { sku:"1", name:"one"},
  { sku:"2", name:"two"}
];
const arrayB = [
  { sku:"1", name:"One Product"},
  { sku:"2", name:"Two Product"},
  { sku:"3", name:"Three Product"}
];

let diff = _.differenceWith(arrayB, arrayA, (a, b) => _.isEqual(a.sku, b.sku) );
```